# How to render interpolated frames in addition to keyframes in python

Tags: python, animation, scripting, keyframes

I am currently using the

```
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=not animate, animation=animate)
```

to render my animation, but this only seems to output the frames on which I inserted a keyframe (with keyframe_insert). Is there a way to render the frames that blender automatically interpolates between the keyframes at a defined framerate?

Thanks in advance.